# How do I navigate to a samba location I've mounted in Nautilus on the command line?

Tags: debian, gnome, samba, nautilus, gvfs

This is [the same question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/33480/45333) ([and a bit of here too](https://askubuntu.com/q/61196/45333)), except that I'm running Debian wheezy (7.4). To clear up, these directories do not exist:

```
/run/user
/var/run/user
~/.cache/gvfs
```

And this directory is empty:

```
~/.gvfs/
```

And the GVFS mounted samba share directory is not found in:

```
/media/
/mnt/
```

Naturally, I'd be expecting the Nautilus explorer to help describe the path I'm looking at, mounted locally. Or "Open in Terminal" to work. But they foil me!

---

Some of the [GVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) utilities show some info from the command line:

```
$ gvfs-mount -l
...
Mount(0): sharedir on wincomp -> smb://wincomp/sharedir/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

or with `gvfs-mount -li`:

```
Mount(0): sharedir on wincomp -> smb://wincomp/sharedir/
  Type: GDaemonMount
  default_location=smb://wincomp/sharedir/
  themed icons:  [folder-remote]  [folder]
  can_unmount=1
  can_eject=0
  is_shadowed=0
```

But it doesn't specify where the local mount location is!

Comment: Have you checked if ~/.gvfs directory exists?

Comment: @adc yes it exists, but is empty

Comment: Usually those are mounted somewhere beneath /media. You can check this with `gvfs-mount`.

Comment: @bjanssen `gvfs-mount -l` shows the mount exists, but doesn't say where. And it isn't under `/media`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. The default installation of Debian Wheezy does not install the POSIX compatibility layer for GVFS. Install it:

`apt-get install gvfs-fuse`

Add your user to the FUSE group:

`adduser <username> fuse`

Reboot your machine (or switch runlevels) and now GVFS will export a FUSE-fs to `/home/<username>/.gvfs/<resourcename>`

Best regards.

See https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/doc for more information, esp. the part about the FUSE daemon.

Comment: Brilliant! Even the "Open in Terminal" feature now works too!

Comment: Looks like the fuse group doesn't exist on Jessie, even after installing gvfs-fuse.

Answer (score 9):

To add to bjanssen's answer, in Debian jessie the SMB share is available at

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs
```

The same applies to your SFTP or WEBDAV shares.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know where samba is mounted try to use "mount" command.
You should see sth like:

```
//123.123.123.8/s /mnt/user/sambaShare smbfs  0 0
```

If you want samba share to be mount in particular directory add to "fstab"

```
//123.123.123.8/s  /mnt/user/sambaShare  smb  username=admin,password=pass 0 0
```

Comment: `mount` doesn't list it, but `gvfs-mount` shows some info for the mount.

Comment: This answer should be correct, unless you are somehow not fully permissioned to see the mount, or it has not actually mounted correctly. Are you running all actions ~as~ root, or through sudo?

Comment: @GeorgeSpiceland mounted as a normal user in Nautilus (via GVFS), and works with Nautilus browser, but apparently hidden/useless to all others, including root.

Comment: @George Spiceland: gvfs is FUSE-based. Only the user mounting the share will see the appropriate gvfs information. I'm looking into this issue (just need to spin up a Debian Wheezy VM), because my curiosity has been spiked. Last time I had to deal with this stuff, gvfs-mount would show entries like gvfs-mount-daemon on /foo/bar etc. Apparently this has changed since Squeeze.

Comment: My weakness with Debian based distro's shines through, thanks for the clarification guys, I may look into this myself.